# Question about DB.Contracts in ASP NET MVC 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type to Boll

```
if( DB.Contacts.Where(c => c.Username == Logon_User))
```

How to compare strings  ?

or

```
var  CheckUser=DataBase.Contacts.Where(c => c.Username == Logon_User)
```

HOW to make the check?

```
"if(CheckUser )"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DB.Contacts.Where` is returning a `Contact` where the `c.Username` equals the logon_user.

If you are just wanting it to return true if any contact's username is the logon try

```
if (DB.Contacts.Any(c => c.Username == Logon_User))
```

Comment: Good answer, especially for a newbie.  Please take a look at the edits and how Stackoverflow supports formatting which makes questions and answers easier to read.

Answer (score -3):

AFAIK you cannot compare strings using the == operator, because it will compare the references of the strings instead, not the strings.
You need to use a String method, like:

String.Equals Method (String)

for example, string1.Equals(string2)

The method will return a boolean.
Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx.aspx

Comment: This is wrong. The == operator will call the Equals() method so they are perfectly equivalent.